# Searching Point in a list by its position

Tags: java, list, contains, point

I have the following problem: I'm working with Lists of Points which look like this

```
List<Point> list = new ArrayList<Point>();
```

Now I'm trying to check whether a new point is already member of the list or not and its previous neighbour by his coordinates.

```
if ((!list.contains(point)) && list.contains(point.getX() - 1)) {
......
}
```

Now the problem is that this expression is never true, although I can clearly see, using a debugger, that a point with the position (x-1, y) which is to the left of it (height is not interesting here) is inside the list and the point itself not.

Any idea?

Comment: Something is weird here.. In the first part of the condition you're checking if the list contains an object of type `Point`, in the second part you're checking if it's containing an `Integer`.. (I assume).. is that correct?

Comment: not an object of a type point, it's the point with its values like x and y. The second you understood correctly. example: my point is (5,5). And i'm checking if there is another point with the value (4,y)

Comment: That's now what you're checking.. see the answer below.

Comment: Yeah but point is an object with setted x and y values. Point point = new Point(). It is not list.contains(Point);

Comment: That's write.. that's why I said it's *of type* `Point`. I hope the answer helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `list.contains(point.getX() - 1)`. You're checking the existence of an *integer* as opposed to a `Point` object. This is because `ArrayList#contains()` takes an `Object` parameter -- the compiler treats the integer as an object and is fine with it.

You need to explicitly pass a `Point` instance, e.g.:

```
Point neighborPoint = new Point(point.getX() - 1, point.getY());

if (!list.contains(point) && list.contains(neighborPoint)) {
   ...
```

Comment: Ah, i see. But then why is it necessary to hava a constructor Point(int x, int y). Why can't i use the awt object-point?

Comment: @JürgenK. I had no idea you were using `java.awt.Point` (you haven't mentioned it anywhere). Yes you can use the available constructor in that class.

Comment: But still i need to write own equals methode? Sorry i thought its clear.

Comment: I missed updating my answer to this. `java.awt.Point` already overrides `equals`.